# Could a 1-2 foot tall (30-60 cm tall) human fly with giant artificial insect wings attached to their back?

Tags: science-based, flight

I'm creating a sub-race of extremely short and technologically advanced humans in my book. These humans, which are dubbed 'faeren' or 'faeries' have created backpacks that have insect wings attached to them, which allow them to hover or fly in the air. Could it be scientifically possible for a human 1-2 foot tall (30-60 cm tall) to be propelled by insect wings of 30 inches (70 cm) wingspan?

Edit: average weight is 31-38 pounds

Comment: Please read the tag description when you pick them. You had chosen two mutually exclusive tags. I have left the less stringent one.

Comment: Sort of a flying one-year old!

Comment: Note.  Size is totally irrelevant in hovering / slow flight.  All that matters is the weight.  You should state the weight.

Comment: note if they are proportioned like humans they will freeze to death fairly quickly.

Answer (score 12):

## At a Stretch

Let's low-ball a $6$ ft person as weighing $64$ kilos. To turn the person into a fairy, simply keep the proportions and divide the height by four. The new height is $6/4=1.5$ foot. The new weight is   $64/4^3 = 1$ kilo.  Can a $1$ kilo animal fly on $30$ cm wings?

---

**Edit:** The question is asking for 30 inch WINGSPAN. Not $30$ cm WING LENGTH. Fortunately it is about the same. If the chest of a $6$ ft man is $12$ inches wide, then the fairy has a chest of $3$ inches or $7.5$ cm. So a $30$ inch or $70$ cm wingspan has $32$ cm long wings.

---

Compare to real animals. We look at falcons since they have short wings for their size. Falcons are built for maneuverability, not for soaring. According to everyone's favourite encyclopedia, the dimensions of everyone's favourite falcon are as follows:

[image]

The bird is $1$-$2$ foot long. It weighs up to $1.5$ kg and has wings $25$-$40$ cm long. Sounds like a $1$ kg bird could fly on $30$ cm wings. Or a $1$ kg person even.

There are other problems to overcome. For example making the person streamlined and using insect wings instead of bird wings. What I can tell you is the numbers you have chosen are in the right area.

**Edit:** Also note we have scaled down the person but not changed the materials. You might shave off a few more ounces by making the bones hollow or removing some organs. Hopefully this will not make the fairy shatter every time it touches the ground.

Comment: Fantastic. This is why we didn't want the green checkmark to show up too early. This has great information. +1

Comment: The 25-40cm in the referenced article is the [chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(aeronautics)) measurement, not the span as the OP was asking. It does also provide a lower limit of wingspan as 29 inches, however this would likely be for relatively small and light individuals, and not for the 1kg weight that was calculated.

Comment: @ThatCoolCoder: I am curious, do you happen to know the wing span (and other related data) for the falcon? Can they be calculated from the wing chord?

Comment: @virolino I just read the wingspan from the wikipedia article screenshot. You could estimate what the wing span would be from the chord, however as different individuals or species could have different [aspect ratios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(aeronautics)) this would not be hugely precise

Comment: @ThatCoolCoder Small falcons have 25ish wings. Big ones have 40ish. 1kg falcons are medium and have wings somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @virolino Wingspan is twice the chord plus the body diameter.

Comment: @virolino estimate the body diameter relative to wingspan using an image like this: https://i2-prod.northantslive.news/incoming/article5210383.ece/ALTERNATES/s1227b/0_Adrian-Howes-Falcon-5.jpg

Comment: not really related, but falcons are crazy! "the highest measured speed of a peregrine falcon is 389 km/h" I knew they were fast, but wow!

Comment: @njzk2 Large animal numbers tend to be estimated rather than measured directly. For 50 years people were claiming Marlins can swim at 40 miles an hour because the encyclopedia said so. The numbers  come down once measured properly. Always be skeptical.

Comment: @Daron apparently that was measured by having a human dive next to a falcon: https://www.smithsonianmag.com/air-space-magazine/falling-with-the-falcon-7491768/

Comment: @njzk2 Wow, that's one super fast human being!

Comment: A major issue is that birds are **incredibly light for their size**.  Note that the question is a bit misguided because **size is irrelevant** for hovering / slow flight.  Simply, this question should be about **weight**.

Comment: Daron, your weight calculation for humans is off by one order of magnitude.  (Humans famously do not at all scale with weight inside a cuboid.)  Quite simply, a 24 inch human weighs about 10 kilos.

Comment: @Fattie I am not convinced.

Comment: Daron, we may be talking at cross purposes, if so sorry.  Millions of 24 inch humans exist (1 year olds) and they weigh 10 kilos.

Comment: @Fattie Babies are much stockier proportionally to an adult. And they have big baby heads. I am talking about perfectly-proportioned scaled down people. They look a bit like these yokes: https://www.google.com/search?q=drawing+mannequin&client=ubuntu&hs=Xin&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxzabClNn9AhWWFMAKHS3wBDcQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1546&bih=818&dpr=1.2

Comment: hi Daron, yes babies are "fatter" than slim adults.  (they're not fatter than American adults)  (Runs away!  :) )  It's a "well known fact" if you will (don't you love when people say that?) that human bodies are not at all mass-proportionate throughout the bounding box, not even slightly. Any game physics programmer who deals with hitboxes, moments of inertia etc all day will have a feel for this.  Anyways, your value, 1kg, is incredibly off.  Sure, if you were saying 5kg, I'd be like "maybe that's a bit off dude".  And again my man, birds are INCREDIBLY light for their bounding box (although

Comment: thats less true for bigger birds, sure, emus etc) Anyway you rock

Comment: PS unrelatedly, as I mention to the Questioner, *"Size is totally irrelevant in hovering / slow flight. All that matters is the weight. You should state the weight ..."*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144567/discussion-between-daron-and-fattie).

Answer (score 6):

**Humans have been having fun with [jet packs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_pack)** (or, at least, the idea of jet packs) since a patent for the idea was filed by Alexander Andreev in 1919. A pack that has mechanical wings rather than jet fuel is really just semantics given your "technologically advanced humans." Rather than rocket fuel, the pack has a very dense "energy source" (aka, a battery, whether it's a "fuel cell" or something else) that operates motors and actuators at, IMO, the speed necessary to be like hummingbirds. After that it's all about material science to develop gossamer wings with the strength and weight characteristics necessary to lift a human.

So, Yup, scientifically plausible.

*When it comes to the description in your world, where you'll have a challenge is explaining stabilization. Hummingbirds use the lower part of their body (not just the tail) along with a tail that can be spread out to different widths, rotated, and pivoted. Think of it as "scooping" or pushing against the air around the hummingbird to stabilize it's motion — or lack of motion. I don't know enough about the physiology of flies to comment, but I suspect a fly will be rotating the wings to achieve a similar affect. Rationalizing the stabilization might be harder than rationalizing the wings.*

BTW, proof of concept is the [helicopter backpack](https://youtu.be/zjDUA0LCs-k), which uses an electrical source (battery...) and the helicopter equivalent of your wings and deals with stabilization in a manner that's more like what I imagine for a fly. Yup, your wings are scientifically plausible.

*Finally, I've ignored the question, "why would you want to do that?" Sometimes we build worlds because it's just too cool to not do it. There are a lot of problems with an insect-wing-style backpack, not the least of which is that wind of almost any strength would be incredibly dangerous. Not just in terms of being pushed into trees or against mountains, but in terms of being pushed into power lines or pushed so far that there's not enough power to get you out of the situation. Wind shear would be incredibly dangerous. Rain, snow, hail (oh... hail), all very dangerous. In other words, there's a real issue of practicality that comes with the idea. But... So honking what? The idea is cool! So go use your wings and remember that [science-based](/questions/tagged/science-based) is a two-edged sword, because along with the technology to build the wings comes the scientific reasons why a society would never build the wings beyond as a hobby.*

Comment: As much as I enjoy receiving that coveted green check mark, we recommend not awarding it for 24-48 hours. We have an amazing group of users all around the world and human nature is to basically not post answers to a question that's already been "solved." You might miss out on some really valuable information.

Comment: ok yeah my mistake